# Flatten dynamic pdf using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext, xfa

I' m using itextsharp to create pdf from template pdf file. But new pdf file is created like dynamic pdf. I want to convert this file to static pdf file, so i tried to use **xfaworker**. I get "Signature was corrupted" error from itextsharp.licensekey.dll. How can i use xfaworker or another dll for flatten dynamic pdf?

```
public string Create(FaxPDFModel model, MemoryStream ms)
{
    string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
    UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
    string templatePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path));
    PdfReader pdfTemplate = new PdfReader(Path.Combine(Path.Combine(templatePath, "Docs"), "fax_template.pdf"));
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfTemplate, ms);
    stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, "ISO-8859-9", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    var acroFields = stamper.AcroFields;
    acroFields.GenerateAppearances = true;
    stamper.FormFlattening = true;
    acroFields.AddSubstitutionFont(bf);
    acroFields.SetField("Name", "Mutabakat test");
    acroFields.SetField("Title", "DANIŞMANLIK");
    acroFields.SetField("Department", "test");
    acroFields.SetField("Phone", "0 (212) 555 55 55");
    stamper.Close();

    string path = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(templatePath, "Docs"), System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    string pdfPath = path + ".pdf";
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(pdfPath, FileMode.Create));
    XFAFlattener xfaf = new XFAFlattener(document, writer);
    ms.Position = 0;   
    xfaf.Flatten(new PdfReader(ms));
    document.Close();
    return pdfPath;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve your problem, you will have to start by fixing the following errors:

**1. You are using code to fill AcroForms instead of code to fill XFA forms:**

If you have a dynamic XFA form, your PDF acts as a container for XML. This form doesn't expect data in the form of key value pairs. This form expects data stored as XML.

You can not use this code:

```
var acroFields = stamper.AcroFields;
acroFields.AddSubstitutionFont(bf);
acroFields.SetField("Name", "Mutabakat test");
acroFields.SetField("Title", "DANIŞMANLIK");
acroFields.SetField("Department", "test");
acroFields.SetField("Phone", "0 (212) 555 55 55");
```

This code expects that your form is an AcroForm. You need to fill the form like this:

```
AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
XfaForm xfa = form.Xfa;
xfa.FillXfaForm(new FileStream(xml, FileMode.Open));
```

In this snippet `xml` refers to the data stored as XML.

**2. You try to flatten the form before flattening the form:**

I see this line in the first part of your code:

```
 stamper.FormFlattening = true;
```

With this line, you remove all interactivity from your PDF. After closing the `stamper` object, you no longer have a form, hence the second part of your code will never work.

**3. You are trying to embed a Standard Type 1 font:**

This line doesn't make sense:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, "ISO-8859-9", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

Times-Roman is a Standard Type 1 font (in the old days, we called this a Base14 font); iText never embeds any of the 14 Standard Type 1 fonts defined for PDF, hence the parameter `BaseFont.EMBEDDED` will be ignored.

**4. The real error:**

XFA Worker is a closed source addon for iTextSharp. It requires a valid license key. When you get an error saying `"Signature was corrupted"`, you are using a license key that is corrupt.

Possible causes:

- You are not a customer of iText Group. You are using a key that you found somewhere and you changed some of its contents.
- You are a customer of iText Group. You received a key, but somehow it got tampered with. In the past, we've had a similar problem where a customer was reading the key as if it was encoded in EBCDIC. Please contact your account manager at iText Group for more info.